# How to get div inside div, not sure where i've gone wrong

Tags: html, css

I need help to get the Portfolio and About div inside the cover hero photo, i don't know why i cant get it in!

Thank you!

[image: image looky]

here's the jsfiddle if you fancy a crack for minimal brain stimulation and helping a friend in need; https://jsfiddle.net/dLnmkvu4/

```
div.cover {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
       background-image: url('SquiggleHero.jpg');
       background-size: cover;
       position: relative;
}       


div.mentionbenjamin { 
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
         }

div.social-links { 
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 150px;
        }

div.header {
        width: 250px;
        height: 70px;
        top: 20px;
        background-color: green;
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 15px;
}

 div.portfolioheader {
         font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
         letter-spacing: 2px;
         color: black;
         font-size: 20px;
         position: absolute;
}

div.aboutheader {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 120px;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the good intentions, but please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: oops, cheers for the link. edited title to be a bit more specific

Comment: Without seeing the corresponding HTML it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: What I meant is you need to add appropriate code and preferably a JSFiddle with a replica of your situation.

Comment: Share HTML part of code as well

Comment: apologises all, rookie level! i've added a jsfiddle, thanks.

Comment: because `portfolioheader` and `aboutheader` are `position: absolute` and don't really have any location information (top, right, bottom, left) (about does and that's why it shows up somewhat how you expect it).

Answer (score 1):

Added `position:absolute;` to your `header`, now they overlap as desired: https://jsfiddle.net/dLnmkvu4/2/

You also had invalid HTML, an unclosed `<center>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First, move your `header` div inside `cover` div.

Then add style `position: relative;` to `cover`.

Then add style `position: absolute;` to `header`.

`header` should absolute aligned with its parent div (`header`), that's why you have `position: relative;` in `cover`. If not, you `header` shall aligned with the `body`, that's not what you want.

**Edit:**

After that, using attributes `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` to re-position your `header`.

Of course, you missed the closing tag `</center>`.

*Sorry for my bad English!*